# GUI Optimization tool for business users

Tags: optimization

We are looking for a tool that can be used by business users where they can do the followings:

1. use a simple data modeler to create the classes of data and populate the data instances
2. simple option to tag data elements to be the decision variables / input or output
3. GUI to create the constraints , turn them on/off
4. Configure the solver options

We are not into using Excel as a candidate tool, and we are looking for a complete GUI based where the whole activity requires no code at all.

Comment: Have a look at Streamlit if you are working with Python.

Comment: @essamSALAH, what exactly you mean by `GUI to create the constraints, turn them on/off`? and `where the whole activity requires no code at all`?

Answer (score 1):

If you know some Python and web languages, check this [post](https://www.danielpradilla.info/blog/linear-optimization-with-or-tools-building-a-web-front-end-with-falcon-and-gunicorn/). It is not exactly what you want but, with some effort, it could be adapted to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting tool would be [***solvgraph***](https://www.solvgraph.com/#/optimization/KNAPSACK/646c9419d3fc73b010e8b403) which was developed by ***@estelle derrien***. It actually tried to show the concept of an optimization model like the objective, constraints, etc. by a drag-and-drop scheme.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[AIMMS](https://www.aimms.com/) could be a viable solution (depending on the number of users and budget) for building interactive GUI for optimization problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).